# Error during instaling NodeJS Fabric Client

Tags: npm, installation, client, hyperledger-fabric

I am installing NodeJS fabric Client locally with valid package.json. But the installation is aborting with following errors.

I tried installing node js fabric client in local folder on visual source code

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hawk@6.0.2: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@3.1.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@4.3.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@2.1.0: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated boom@5.2.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

> grpc@1.10.1 install C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\go\\src\\trade-finance-logistics-master\\middleware\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\go\\src\\trade-finance-logistics-master\\middleware\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\go\\src\\trade-finance-logistics-master\\middleware\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Lenovo\go\src\trade-finance-logistics-master\middleware\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm WARN middleware@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-01T18_33_47_574Z-debug.log
```

the package.json file:

"dependencies": {
    "fabric-ca-client": "^1.1.2",
    "fabric-client": "~1.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^2.0.0",
    "jsrsasign": "6.2.2",
    "tape": "^4.5.1",
    "tape-promise": "^1.1.0"
  },

expected result: Installation should be successful
Actual result : Installation aborting with errors

Comment: More specifically I am seeing the following error :gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)

Comment: why does it need a python variable or why is it looking for this config ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the node-sass dependencies is node-gyp which needs to be built before it can be run and this uses Python 2.7 to be installed on the system.

A package called **windows-build-tools** will fix this issue.

Install the dependency first and then try to install NodeJS Fabric Client.

Hope it helps:)